# SQL full backup and differential backup query

Tags: backup, sql-server

I have a question regarding SQL backups. We have 3 SQK servers (A, B and C). I'm taking a full backup of a DB from server A and restoring it on server B. After that I'm taking a differential backups of the same DB from server A for restoring on server B.

My question is, can I restore the initial full backup of the DB from server A on server C and then, restore the differential backups of the same DB from server B onto server C?

The reason I'm doing this is, we have a storage issue on sServer B, therefore we're not able to take full backups of the DB from server B, so intending to use the full backup from server A in server C and differential backups from server B in server C. Hope this is not confusing.

Comment: It's not confusing but it doesn't make any sense. Why would you use differential backups from B if you already got a differential from A?

Comment: Missed that part, Server A is going down, there's only Server B and C we can use, so full backup from A -> B & C and differential backup from B -> C

Comment: But that still doesn't make any sense unless you describe what system they're actually running on. Are they independent? If so why would you need a differential backup? Are they clustered? If so why do you need a differential backup and the synch doesn't happen automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about mixing backups from different servers during the restore operation I've made a lab like this:

- SQLA (SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU12))
- SQLB (SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU12))
- SQLC (SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU12))

Created a database named **TestRestore** on full recovery mode and a table **tbTest** to have some data to check later.
The backup and restore experiment followed like this:

**1. Executed on SQLA**

Creates the database and sets recovery mode full

```
CREATE DATABASE TestRestore;
GO
ALTER DATABASE TestRestore SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

Connects to TestRestore database, creates a table and inserts some data

```
USE TestRestore;
CREATE TABLE tbTest(ID int);
INSERT INTO tbTest(ID) VALUES(1),(2),(3);
GO
```

Backup the database (Full backup)

```
BACKUP DATABASE TestRestore 
    TO DISK = '\\networkBackupShare\TestRestore_SQLA_FULL.bak';
GO
```

**2. Executed on SQLB**

```
RESTORE DATABASE TestRestore 
    FROM DISK = '\\networkBackupShare\TestRestore_SQLA_FULL.bak'
    WITH RECOVERY;
GO
```

Here I inserted some data to the table on SQLB server before taking the DIFF backup.

```
USE TestRestore;
INSERT INTO tbTest(ID) VALUES(4),(5),(6);
GO

BACKUP DATABASE TestRestore  
   TO DISK = '\\networkBackupShare\TestRestore_SQLB_DIFF.bak'
   WITH DIFFERENTIAL;  
GO
```

Finally inserted the last bit of data to the table before taking the LOG backup.

```
INSERT INTO tbTest(ID) VALUES(7),(8),(9);
GO

BACKUP LOG TestRestore  
   TO DISK = '\\networkBackupShare\TestRestore_SQLB_LOG.bak';
GO
```

**3. Executed on SQLC**

Now let's restore our Frankenstein monster and see what happens:

```
RESTORE DATABASE TestRestore 
    FROM DISK = '\\networkBackupShare\TestRestore_SQLA_FULL.bak'
    WITH NORECOVERY;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE TestRestore 
    FROM DISK = '\\networkBackupShare\TestRestore_SQLB_DIFF.bak'
    WITH NORECOVERY;
GO
RESTORE LOG TestRestore 
    FROM DISK = '\\networkBackupShare\TestRestore_SQLB_LOG.bak' 
    WITH RECOVERY;  
GO
```

**It worked!**

[image: Messages from restore commands on SQLC]

**Conclusion:**
Yes, you can mix backup files that came from different servers if the database has the same origin. Beware of two facts though:

1. The database resulted on server SQLC is a copy of the last state of SQLB, not SQLA.
2. The experiment only worked because the backup chain hasn't been broken (like taking a FULL BACKUP on SQLB before taking the DIFF and LOG backups), otherwise you'd get a message like this:

[image: Error message from backup restore]

Comment: Thank you taking time to do this, i just wanted to check if somebody had already tried this, i'm gonna try this with the actual full back up, thank you once again